# Need a notification that DLL is shutting down before getting DLL_PROCESS_DETACH

Tags: c++, windows, dllmain

We have a DLL built in Visual Studio using C++11.  Our DLL has a fixed API at this point, and it includes an `open` and `close` function (among others).  We allow our users to `open` and `close` multiple times without closing the app.  Inside our DLL, we are using a 3rd party library that has not only an `open` and `close`, but also an `initialize` and `uninitialize`.

The `open` and `close` map closely to our `open` and `close`, but the `initialize` and `uninitialize` are to be called only once each, at start up and shut down. I am able to call their `initialize` only once from our `open` function, but I cannot find a place to call the `uninitialize`, as I don't know when the app is about to be shut down. The most logical place to call it from is in the `DllMain` function under the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, and while this works when running under debug, when I run under release we get an unhandled exception, "Fatal program exit requested."  If I just give up and remove their `uninitialize` call, I still get an unhandled exception and in neither case do I cleanly shut down.

Is there any way to get a signal/notification that the application is shutting down prior to `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`?

Comment: you need research why unhandled exception first

Comment: and for what you need this notification before ? why you decide that `uninitialize` not crashed inside this notification ?

Comment: A fatal app exit (`FAST_FAIL_FATAL_APP_EXIT`) can happen for various reasons, such as calling C `abort`. To directly address the problem, you need to analyze the exception, find the immediate cause, and investigate further with breakpoints. It may be an upstream bug that you can report, and work around until it gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such notification inside a DLL.  `DllMain()` is the only place the DLL knows what is going on.  Its `lpReserved` parameter will tell you whether `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is due to a call to `FreeLibrary()` or not. That is about all you get from the system.

Either debug the code to find out why the exception is occurring, and then fix it or catch it.

Or, keep track of how many times your DLL's `open()` and `close()` are called.  Call the lib's `initialize()` on the 1st `open()`, and call the lib's `uninitialize()` on the last matching `close()`.  And then make sure the app calls your `close()` on shutdown.

Or, add your own `initialize()` and `uninitialize()` to your DLL to call the lib's corresponding functions, and then make the app call your `initialize()` at startup/open and your `uninitialize()` at shutdown.